# How to make Custom GIF Keyboard in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have one doubt that how exactly GIF images loaded into Custom keyboard and user can send it. I am new in iOS so want some link which i can refer and will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Read Apple docs for this, especially this one https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html is a good strating point
You can set any UIView as the view for the keyboard layout, so an UIImageView is suitable for your purpose. The real difficulty in custom keyboarding is the management of events. As you are new to iOS dev, I would like to encourage you to try much simpler things first.